# How to use PostConstruct in Plain Java

Tags: java, java-8

I am developing Plain java code (no bean or container frameworks) and I wanted to achieve `@PostConstruct` / `@PreDestroy` functionalities. Is that possible ?

I wrote a sample code to check the feasibility (code sample below). But the postContruct() and beforeDestroy() methods are not getting called.

**How to achieve this ?**

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

public class Test {

    public static void main (String...strings) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println("Ready....");
        test.sayHello();
        System.out.println("Done...");

    }

    private void sayHello () {
        System.out.println("Hello World !! ");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("PostConstruct is called .. ");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void beforeDestroy () {
        System.out.println("beforeDestroy is called ");
    }

}
```

The Output is

```
Ready....
Hello World !! 
Done...
```

Comment: Without framework, it's not possible. Either use one, or make one. Without any *visible* framework, you might want to use things like Java Annotation Processing which allow to change your code at the compilation time, but I'm not even sure it's feasible in that regards. The really complex case is `@PreDestroy`. In your code, you'd typically require to add hooks to the shutdown. You could also use the `finalize` method (of `Object`), but then... all bets are off.

Comment: Without a framework, the only person who will be constructing these objects is you, and the only way it will occur is via the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments that were mentioned on your question already state it: if you don't use a framework or tool that handles the annotations, then no, there is no way that those `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy`-methods get called. As a side-note: you could also write your own AnnotationProcessor, but you will probably ending up writing a framework, where you could just use something like a CDI container of your choice (e.g. Weld, OpenWebBeans, etc.).

Now, how could you solve it without annotations? It depends what you want to achieve.

For example, if it doesn't really matter, that the `@PostConstruct` isn't called exactly after the construction of the object, then an instance initalization block may serve your needs, e.g.

```
class Some {

  {
    // your initialization code... however! this is not the same as @PostConstruct 
  }
}
```

Regarding the `@PreDestroy` you could overwrite [`Object.finalize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()).

Be careful when you supply your own `finalize`-implementation and read some articles regarding it, before you do.

Both solutions however are not 1:1 substitutes of the annotations, but they may be what you are looking for.

Here is an example class:

```
class PreDestroyPostConstruct {

  PreDestroyPostConstruct() {
    System.out.println("constructor");
  }

  {
    System.out.println("initialization block");
  }

  @Override
  protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("finalize");
  }
}
```

Demonstrating the output:

```
PreDestroyPostConstruct obj = new PreDestroyPostConstruct();
obj = null;
System.out.println("Program finishing");
```

Possible output:

```
initialization block
constructor
finalize
Program finishing
```

Note, that there is no guarantee that `finalize` is called before the `"Program finishing"`-part and it may even happen that it isn't called/finished before the VM shuts down.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you can have a static factory method that calls an `init` method after it has constructed the Object.

```
private final init(){
     .. your stuff after the constructor
}

public static MyObject of(int x){
    MyObject obj = new MyObject(x);
    init();
    return obj;
}
```

You could do the same inside the constructor, but I don't like calling methods inside a constructor. In case you do, that method has to be **final** so that it does not get overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest way would be implement your own annotations and an utility class to manage instances, then you can execute methods for the post construct after instantiating the class and pre destroy before destroying the reference.

Calling a method last in a constructor would be practically the same, i dont imagine any case where its different.

Calling finalize is also a good option if you know what you are doing becaue it could not be called depending in the jvm and system configuration but that actually isnt a pre destructor it would be a destructor itself since you cant throw exceptions

You can implement AutoCloseable interface and instantiate the class in a try with resources and implement the close method thats going to be called